# How to say "I like watching birds"

Tags: translation, phrases, phrase-requests

The title explains it all. I think that one would say (mind you I'm just starting out, so I will write everything in hiragana) わたしはとりがながめるのすきです。Would that be correct? Or am I totally wrong, and if so, how do you actually say it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 私は鳥を見るのが好きです　(watashi wa tori wo miru no ga suki desu) - I like to watch birds/watching birds

You had a couple things wrong in your sentence, for instance, after 鳥(bird) you need the particle **を** because this particle is the one required when an action is happening towards something.

The action of seeing is happening towards the bird, if you use **が** it feels like the birds that are doing the "watching" and not yourself.

also it lacked the **が** particle before **好き(suki)**, this particle marks the subject of watching, since it marks a verb, you correctly nominalized it with **の**.

> 見るのが好きです(miru no ga suki desu) - I like to watch.

Often in common speech we often have no need to say **私は** if it is implicit by the context, that is you who likes to watch birds.

So the sentence could be like that:

> 鳥を見るのが好きです　(tori wo miru no ga suki desu) - I like to watch birds.

or in a more casual way:

> 鳥を見るの好きです (tori wo miru no suki desu) - I like to watch birds. (dropping ga particle in casual speech often happens as well)

Comment: I will leave my answer as it is, if the main reason for you making this question was understanding some grammar points. If you were looking for the right "technical" terms,  @A.Ellett answer is the way to go, I think

Comment: 鳥を見る好き doesn't make sense. It should be 鳥を見るの好き.

Comment: @user4092 will correct it!

Answer (score 6):

ながめる has more of a sense of "gaze at" than "watch".  You might want to use 観察{かんさつ}.  I think the rather technical term for bird watching is [野鳥]{やちょう}[観察]{かんさつ}.  So you could write 野鳥観察が[好]{す}きです.

Comment: 「バードウォッチングが好きです」でもいいかも？

Answer (score 1):

I believe [野鳥]{やちょう}[観察]{かんさつ}, as mentioned above, is correct and used in proper writing. But I feel it is used less and less. I think バード・ウォッチング ("bird watching"), pulled from the English, would be widely understood to mean the hobby of bird watching.

Two spellings are common, バードウォッチング and バードウオッチング, but I believe the first one, with the small オ, is more popular.